# Cannot connect to internal IP on interface

Tags: networking, lan

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04.
I have a static IP assigned to the network interface on the server.
This IP is routable from outside the LAN
I am wanting to access the same server from the internal LAN via a private IP address as well.
Network interface is referred to as eth0

I added this to my /etc/network/interfaces config

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.163.1.153
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.3
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.3
```

With this added, should I be able to access my Ubuntu server from the internal LAN as well?

I did notice when running `systemctl restart networking` I get the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Jun 29 18:37:28 confluence ifup[2522]: Failed to bring up eth0:1.
```

So I have to assume that this is why its not listening on the private IP. I just cant figure out why its not listening / starting up.

Would it be better to add another virtual NIC to the machine and assign it the private IP or is it just as effective to assign a private and public IP to the same interface? Or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the static address for your server is misconfigured. What was your reasoning for choosing 192.163.1.153?

Your gateway and DNS servers are on a different network **192.168.1**, vs **192.163.1**

Comment: Wow I totally fat fingered that!!  FIxed the IP address and now it works.